# Python pandas dataframe getting NaN instead of values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a large dataset where multiple columns had NaN values. I used `python pandas` to replace the missing values in few columns by mean and the rest by median. I got rid of all the NaN values and wrote the resultant the Dataframe to a new file.

Now when I read the new file again it contains NaNs instead of values. I am unable to figure out why is this happening. Below is my code for reference:

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_csv('temp_train.csv',header=0)
df.prop_review_score=df.prop_review_score.fillna(0)
mean_score_2 = np.mean(df.prop_location_score2)
df.prop_location_score2 = df.prop_location_score2.fillna(mean_score_2)
median_search_query = np.median(df.srch_query_affinity_score)
df.srch_query_affinity_score = df.srch_query_affinity_score.fillna(median_search_query)
median_orig_distance = np.median(df.orig_destination_distance)
df.orig_destination_distance = df.orig_destination_distance.fillna(median_orig_distance)
df.to_csv('final_train_data.csv')
```

Now in another script when I type the following I get `NaNs` in `srch_query_affinity_score`

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_csv('final_train_data.csv',header=0)
print df
```

Comment: While probably a large file, it should be possible to manually inspect "final_train_data.csv" and look for anything NaN-like. Otherwise, is it possible to provide a small "temp_train.csv" (possibly just a few rows) that has these NaN issues, so that other people can reproduce the problem?

Comment: Evert, I saw the file in Sublime Text and searched for NaN and it didn't find any NaNs.

Comment: I would go line by line, and save the file and then work out at which line the code appears to be breaking down. Are the only possible NaN's in `prop_review_score`? If not then clearly means with NaNs are NaNs so that might be causing the problem...

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to use `pandas.DataFrame.median` instead of `numpy.median` on the dataframe.

A quick test for me shows (when there are NaNs in the data as Woody suggests):

`df = pd.DataFrame({'x':[10,pd.np.NAN,np.NAN,20]})
df.x.median()    # returns 20.0
np.median(df.x)  # returns NaN`

So consider replacing:

`median_search_query = np.median(df.srch_query_affinity_score)`
with
`median_search_query = df.srch_query_affinity_score.median()`

To make sure before you go to csv do something like:

`assert df.srch_query_affinity_score.isnull().sum() == 0`

Comment: This is in the exceptional case where there are an equal number of NaNs and actual data: pandas appears to mask/ignore the NaNs, numpy includes them. Perhaps the OP does have this case, but it appears somewhat exceptional. Numpy 1.9, btw, has the function `nanmedian`, which also ignores NaNs.